# Prepending parent selectors in SCSS

Tags: sass

I want to nest selectors by prepending the parent selector in SCSS.

The basic selector is:

```
.selector-class .selector-class__element {}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="selector-class">
    <div class="selector-class__element"></div>
</div>
```

**(A)** Here is the desired result in SCSS:

```
.selector-class {
    .selector-class__element {

    }
}
```

**(B)** This is the idea behind how I want to do it: *(Does not work)*

```
.selector-class {
    &__element {

    }
}
```

Is there a more effecient way of doing it than using the method in **(A)** ?

Comment: So the desired selector is `.selector-class .selector-class__element`?

Comment: Yes indeed - added this to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add an extra ampersand at the beginning:

```
.selector-class {
    & &__element {
      background: red;
    }
}
```

Comment: This throws me a syntax error: `"Syntax error: Invalid CSS after \" & &\": expected \"{\"`

Comment: Sass 3.3.8 (Maptastic Maple)

Comment: Are you also using Compass?  The current stable version (0.12) is incompatible with Sass 3.3

Comment: Oh man, that will be the problem then. I have to update to Ruby 2.1 on Mavericks for Compass 1 to work. Taking a while, hopefully this will fix it.

Comment: Ok this works now with SASS: 3.3.8 and Compass: 1.0.0.alpha.19

Comment: In fact the way I wanted to do it in the original question works with those versions too. Doesn't require two &.

Answer (score 1):

You need to try this one. This is just an example for both class and element. You may try any one of them.

```
.selector-class {
   &.class, &div { background: blue; }
}
```

EDIT
Below is the interpolation method of concatenating string.

```
.selector-class {
   &#{'__element'} { background: blue; }
}
```

CSS

```
.selector-class .selector-class__element { background: blue; }
```

more about interpolation

[interpolation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_)

Comment: The whole point is to avoid writing out the entire `&.class` again.

Comment: You can avoid &.class and move to &#{'__element'}  . Does it helps ?

Comment: I am not sure what you meann with the &#{'__element'}

Comment: I just updated. Thats an interpolation method of sass. It helps to connect string.

Comment: Hmm interesting, thanks for the link. For some reason the interpolation does not work with the ampersand selector!

Comment: The updated answer doesn't produce the desired output (even if it was corrected to do so, it would be just a more verbose version of the existing answer).

Comment: Yeap, I did try but no success.